Is it possible to webassembly a C++ Windows application using emscripten:
I have a complex windows application that uses MFC and some OpenGL.
I'd like to use Webassembly https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten
to use emscripten to convert the c++ application to web.
But the windows MFC application was developed using MSVC as a usual windows c++ .sln using Microsoft Visual Studio.
Is it possible to convert my application to LLVM and so use emscripten or this is a not feasible task?

That would only work if there would be a full windows emulator available in web-assembly.  It does not exist... and if it would I think microsoft lawyers would have to say a thing or to about that. I hope your app has a good architecture (seperate model/busineslogic and presentation layer... if not refactor it to be like that)

@PepijnKramer It exists

Run the application on a virtual machine and use web console or other web client.

@Dai well ok windows 95 might run a very old version of MFC. But to expose that to the web? ... security alert
